# How to check string contains sub string in bash script

Tags: bash

I am working on scripting and using bash shell for execution.
Following are two different variations that I am trying to  execute.
but its not working not on execution there is error on console for double bracket in if condition.

```
#!/bin/bash

STR='GNU/Linux is an operating system'
    SUB='Linux'
    if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]
    then
      echo "It's there."
    else
        echo "Not It's there."
    fi  
    

    if [[ $STR =~ $SUB ]]; then
        echo found
    else
        echo not found
    fi
```

[image]

I took the reference of this example from https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-check-if-string-contains-substring-in-bash/  . now not sure why its not working.
But in my project, following syntax is working fine. Here I was checking for equality which works fine but in above example I want to verify contains.

```
if [ $1= "test" ]
    then
     test=true
    elif [ $1= "dev ]
    then
     dev=true
    fi
```

Bash Version

[image]

OS

[image]

can someone help me ?

Comment: what do you mean by this @Cyrus. I did not get any answer yet

Comment: Does everything work when you remove the forward slash in "GNU/Linux"?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, unfortunately not. it complains on double bracket in if condition. I had similar issue with the last example and I had removed double brackets [[ to single [.

Comment: I just tried your code on Bash 4.4 in Linux and Bash 5.1.8 in MSYS2 and it worked fine.  I copied and pasted it into a script named `test.sh`, marked it as executable, and then ran `./test.sh`.  The output was `It's there` followed by `found`.  Could you give more details about your environment and exactly how you are running code?  Did you copy and paste the exact code that you are running into this question?

Comment: Your second example is wrong, but the first is fine. Are you using an other shell than bash for launching it?

Comment: @DavidGrayson, updated question with bash and OS details

Comment: @Fravadona, when I execute echo "$SHELL" then it prints /bin/bash. so I am sure its bash.

Comment: @DavidGrayson, David was write, this file doesn't has any extension and I was using sh test like command . But its working with /bin/bash test command now.

Comment: `$SHELL` doesn't necessarily reflect the shell you're actually running at the time; it's just your preferred one.

Comment: @StillLearning When you use `sh scriptname` to run the script, it ignores the shebang and uses whatever `sh` is on your system (maybe bash, maybe dash, maybe something else). Make the script executable (`chmod +x scriptname`) and run it with `./scriptname` to have it follow the shebang.

Comment: @Cyrus, generally I always accept answer and do follow-up also. Not sure I missed someone's answer un-acceptable. Sorry for that and will keep in mind.

Comment: `if [[ $STR =~ $SUB ]]; then` looks just fine for bash.

Comment: it's not clear (to me) how you obtained the bash version ... `bash --version` or `/bin/bash --version` (the latter is needed to verify the script's shebang is actually calling `bash`); the first error message (a link/image) seems to indicate the error is from line 25 of the script but we've only been provided with (the first?) 17 lines of the script ... is there more to the script than what has been provided?

Answer (score 3):

I think you have two problems:

First, you're running the scripts with `sh`, not `bash`.

Second, `[ $1= "test" ]` is invalid syntax (in either shell). There must be a space before `=`. If you do `[ $1= "test" ]` in `sh` you will get the error `unexpected operator` (as in your screen capture). Whereas bash will print `unary operator expected`.

Double square brackets (`[[`) and globs (`*"$SUB"*`) in string matching are bash syntax, and are not available in `sh`. If you run the first `if` statement from your first example in `sh`, it will not print an error, but it *will* always evaluate to false (printing `Not It's there.`), wether the substring matches or not, due to `[[`.

So, you should fix the syntax errors: `[ $1= "test" ]` should be `[ "$1" = "test" ]`.

You should also run your script with `bash`, not `sh`, to use bash specific syntax:

You can call the script like `bash script-file` or `bash /path/to/script-file`.

Or, make sure the script is executable: `chmod a+x script-file`, and call it with a full path: `./script-file` or `/path/to/script-file`.

Your shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) is correct if on Linux. On another platform you can try `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.